# DirectX on Windows Phone 8 - Context/Device lost on minimizing

Tags: c++, xaml, c++11, directx, windows-phone

I am using XAML/C# + C++ app with `DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid` for DirectX11 as interop.

When using [DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.drawingsurfacebackgroundgrid%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) it seems that `Connect()` and `Disconnect()` are called immediately when the app is suspended to background.

When `Disconnect()` is called, DX Context and Device are lost. This causes me having to re-load all textures. Sound and music are not removed and instead are resumed.

I've tried a few `DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid` and they all seem to have the same issue.

This doesn't happen when using native code. I was wondering if there is any way to handle pausing/resuming of apps when using XAML and not have it `Disconnect()` on minimizing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find anything too, but it seems Microsoft forces us to recreate Shaders/Textures etc to keep memory for other apps. If you think about it, that's not a bad situation ! It's just a boring behavior to code, that's it... DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid is full of surprises !